# How to feed multiple initial guesses in curve_fit?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am fitting data to a model with 10 free parameters. Currently, I am using the function `curve_fit` from the module `scipy` in Python.

The result seems to be very sensitive to the choice of the initial guess and therefore I would like to run the fitting program using an array of initial values for each one of the parameters, this in order to find the global minima and not a local one when optimizing.

I am fairly new in python and I was wondering which could be a good approach to carry out this. Is there a parameter of the `curve_fit` function that can help me on this? Is there another more appropriate function? or should I resort to doing a very long nested for-loop for sweeping all the possible values of the different initial parameters?

Please give me your suggestions,

Thanks!

Comment: If the points to be checked are part of a grid, you can use scipy's brute and wrap your curve-fit. But it's questionably, if a simple *loop-based* approach is not more clear / painfree. Btw: you probably won't need real loops: just use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). And another tip: the most relevant tag here (besides python) would be scipy (and many of the ones used are not helping much) and your actual lib in use is probably *scipy* (and not *spicy*).

Comment: You can also use the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to determine initial parameters. This scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space and so requires bounds within which to search - however those bounds can be generous. I have an example of fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes using this scipy module at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit if it might be of some use.